# Check whether the web-driver is up in Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have written some test cases in Robot Framework and my project structure is like this:

```
TestProject
|__ TestScenarios
    |__ TestCategory1
    |__ TestCategory2
    |__ __init__.py
|__ RunTest.py
```

I have a `suit setup` which opens browser with a given URL and a `suit teardown` which closes all browsers in `__init__.py`. I call `RunTest.py` in order to run my test cases; I set which directory should be included or excluded in tests and some other preferences in `RunTest.py`.

If I set the test directory from top directory, i.e. `TestScenarios`, `__init__.py` would be called. But when I set sub-directories for run, `__init__.py` logically is not going to be called and so there would be no browsers. If I add another `__init__.py` files into sub-directories, it would be problematic if I run test from top directory; there would be multiple browsers.

What I want is to add one `__init__.py` file into each sub-directory, but in these new `__init__.py` files, I'll check whether the browser is open or not and if yes, I'll continue with current one, otherwise I'll open a new browser. So. I can easily switch between directories.

Any help how can I do what I have talked about in the last paragraph??

Comment: I am a bit confused about __init__.py file. Does that contain Python code or Robot Framework keywords? I know you can initialize test suites with __init__.txt but not with __init__.py

Comment: @Pekka, it contains Robot Framework keywords. It acts similar to `__init__.py` in python packages. Whenever the `RunTest.py` script enters a directory, if it contains `__init__.py` file, that would be the first file for execution.

Comment: Why not just always run from the top directory? You can turn on or off sub-suites using command line options.

Comment: @BryanOakley, it's somehow related to our Jenkins's automation process.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi: I don't understand that response. Are you saying you don't have control over how jenkins runs your tests?

Comment: @BryanOakley, apparently yes. Those configuration are somehow fixed based on some standards and I can't change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to run a keyword that you know will fail if no browser is open. If the keyword fails, open the browser. If it succeeds, do nothing.

It might look something like this:

```
*** Keywords ***
| Maybe open browser
| | # Don't capture screenshot if this fails
| | ${fail keyword}= | Register keyword to run on failure | Nothing
| | 
| | # Run a keyword and capture the status
| | ${status}= | run keyword and return status | Get Window Identifiers
| | 
| | # Reset the run-on-failure keyword
| | Register keyword to run on failure | ${fail keyword}
| | 
| | # Return if the keyword succeeds, on the assumption
| | # that a browser window is already open
| | Run keyword unless | ${status} == False | Return from keyword 
| | 
| | # No browser was open, so open one
| | log | No browser was previously open
| | Open browser | http://www.google.com | chrome
```

In my opinion, the best solution is to always run your tests from the root folder, and use command line arguments and tags to run specific suites.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess` module to see the live processes and check if your browser is open or not :

```
import subprocess

def __init__(proc_name,flag=False):
   p = subprocess.Popen(['ps','-A'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   out, err = p.communicate()
   for line in out.splitlines():
      if proc_name in line:
          print line
          flag=True
          # continue with current proc
          #pid = int(line.split(None, 1)[0]) if you need pid 
   if not flag:
          #start new proc
```

If you want to kill a process you can sue `os,kill` like following :

```
os.kill(pid, subprocess.signal.SIGKILL)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I just want Robot keywords, if possible!

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi Welcome, but I didn't get that  what you mean by ` Robot keywords` also I'm not familiar with `robot` and actually testing, I just suggest a way for at python's perspective!

Comment: It's really nice of you. I totally appreciate that. :-)